# bundle_errors in flask_restplus is not returning the errors for the missing arguments

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I implemented a very simple API using flask-restplus, however I ran into an issue when I tried to use `bundle_errors=True` with the `reqparse`.
For the following code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=False)
parser.add_argument('username', type=list, required=True, help="Missing Username", location="json")
parser.add_argument('password', type=list, required=True, help="Missing Password", location="json")

@api.route('/user')
class User(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return {"ID":"1", "Username": args['username'], "Password": args['password']}, 201


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

1- When **`bundle_errors=False`** and I send a request with missing parameters

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5051/user 
  -H 'content-type: application/json'
  -d '{}'
```

I get the following response

```
{
    "errors": {
        "username": "Missing Username"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

Which is fine except that is showed only one missing field.

2- When I used **`bundle_errors=True`** (as mentioned in the documentation), I got the following result

```
{
    "Username": "Missing required parameter in the JSON body",
    "Password": "Missing required parameter in the JSON body",
    "ID": "1"
}
```

Which means that RequestParser didn't throw any error and returned this string "Missing required parameter in the JSON body" as the actual input

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using python version 3.5.2 and flask-restplus==0.10.1